# Maintaining hashCode contract for the specific condition, equals() depending on two integers

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I have a basic class with the structure:

```
class Employee {
int eId;
String eName;

Employee(int id, String name) {
    this.eId= id;
    this.eName= name;
}
```

The conditions for equality is such that `equals()` should return true if *any* of the following is true:

1. `eId` are same.
2. `eName` are same.
3. Lengths of `eName` are same.

I had no problem in overriding `equals()`, however, in order to maintain the hash code contract, I should override `hashCode()` as well. So, the hashCode should depend on `eId` and `eName.length()` (if `eName`s are equal, their lengths will be equal as well). So there are four cases:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(4, "John");
Employee e2 = new Employee(3, "Jane");
Employee e3 = new Employee(4, "Jim");
Employee e4 = new Employee(7, "Random");
```

`hashCode()` should return the same value for `e1`, `e2`, and `e3` and a different value for `e4`. I can't come up with the logic satisfying this requirement.

Here is the exact problem:

> Create a class (having parameters name, id etc). Show that if 2 objects of this class will be compared then they should return true in any of below case :
>
> A. Id of both are same.
>
> B. Name of both are same.
>
> C. Length of name’s of both are same.
>
> Make sure HashCode contract should not violate.

Comment: I think, the requirement should be `ALL` of the conditions are met, not `ANY`. As other people mentioned, it violates the `transitivity`

Comment: On the basis of the quoted assignment, the only possible valid `.hashCode()` implementation is one that returns an arbitrary constant (e.g. `0`) for all `Employee` instances.

Comment: Yeah, its as I thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're running into trouble because your notion of equality is inconsistent.  Specifically, it's not transitive, which the contract for [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) requires.

> It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.

Under your definition, `e1` equals `e2` and `e3`, but `e2` does not equal `e3`.  This is incompatible with Java's notion of equality.  This is also why you're running into trouble defining a reasonable `.hashCode()` implementation.

However what you can do is define a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (or [`Ordering`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/OrderingExplained), if you're using Guava).  For most use cases (like sorting, searching, or filtering) you should be able to use a separate `Comparator` instance just like you would the `.equals()` method.  You are effectively trying to define *equivalent* objects, not *equal* objects.

If you can't use a separate `Comparator` for whatever reason, your `Employee` object will be fundamentally inconsistent, and will prove problematic even if you should get a "workable" `.hashCode()` implemented.

Comment: Yes, I agree, and that's exactly the problem. But, this is a college assignment and I tried discussing it, with no effect on the teacher.

So, I can ignore transitivity for this particular case, if I can get a 'workable' hashCode()

Comment: @neo.one Well, a "workable" `.hashCode()` would simply return `0` for all `Employee` objects.  But that is surely not the desired behavior for your assignment.  Either you misunderstand the requirements of the assignment (post them verbatim in the question, if you want) or you are supposed to use a `Comparator`.

Comment: Put another way, suppose you create a "workable" `.hashCode()` implementation, your `.equals()` method is, by definition, incorrect.  It doesn't really matter what `.hashCode()` does if `.equals()` is broken.

Comment: I thought about that, returning a '0', or any other int will at least maintain hashCode contract, but that isn't acceptable by the examiner.So unless, I can solidly tell him that the conditions makes it impossible to get a workable hashCode() in the situation, I'll have to try.

Comment: @neo.one It is impossible to define a transitively equivalent object on the basis of `object.a` *or* `object.b` being equal.  But your instructor knows that already (or you have much bigger problems than this assignment ;) ).  It is likely you are misunderstanding some aspect of the assignment.  If you post your assignment verbatim, we can help clarify the confusion.

Comment: I've updated the question with the assignment problem. Do check and if I'm not understanding it then please correct me.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, you cannot write a consistent `hashCode` in your case, because your `equals` breaks the contract of [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, namely transitivity:

> It is *transitive*: for any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, and `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` should return `true`.

Suppose you have this code:

```
Employee a = new Employee(1, "John");
Employee b = new Employee(1, "James");
Employee c = new Employee(2, "James");
```

In this case with your equals operation `a.equals(b)` and `b.equals(c)`, but not `a.equals(c)`.

I'd suggest to rethink the implementation of `equals`. Probably your `Employee` has either `eId` or `eName` defined, so it might be better to add a `boolean` field which says whether `eId` or `eName` should be used. This way you can easily implement `equals` and `hashCode`. This way the implementation might be like this (assuming for simplicity that `eName` cannot be `null`):

```
class Employee {
    boolean useName;
    int eId = 0;
    String eName;

    Employee(int id) {
        this.eId = id;
        this.useName = false;
    }

    Employee(String name) {
        this.eName = name;
        this.useName = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return useName ? eName.length() * 1337 : eId * 7331;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (useName != other.useName)
            return false;
        if (useName) {
            if (eName.length() != other.eName.length())
                return false;
        } else {
            if (eId != other.eId)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would an `Employee` have either an ID or a name and never both?  OP's constructor expects both.

Comment: It's my assumption that it's reasonable for OPs original task. Probably it's wrong.

Comment: The Employee has both, and yes, I'm aware the condition are defying transitivity but its a college assignment and was presented with specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7, then I think it's easy by using java.util.Objects:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(eld,eName.length());
}
```

Or you can can consider [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), it has a same method under `com.google.common.base.Objects`

Comment: OP wants objects to be equivalent when *either* `eId` or `eName.length()` are equal.  This will only treat `Employee`s as equal when *both* values are the same.